# How to play .MOV video file on Ionic 3?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have tried using Ionic Native Video Player, however, it doesn't work. When I tried to play any videos, it just shows a black screen with no audio or whatsoever. Then, I tried HTML5 video tag. However, it only works for MP4 and doesn't work for .MOV file.

Is there any plugins or solution for this?

Ionic Native Video Player

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

    this.videoPlayer
      .play("../../assets/sample.mov")
      .then(() => {
       console.log("video completed");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
}
```

HTML5 Video Player

```
<video fullscreen="fullscreen" autoplay="true">
    <source src="../../assets/sample.mov" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code working fine in my project

```
<video fullscreen="fullscreen" autoplay="true">
     <source src="../../assets/sample.mov" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFHY6.png)